# How find contour of the 3D model?

Tags: three.js, 3d

Question.
We need to cut the shape of the window in the walls using a Boolean method ala Blender. Can anyone suggest something about this in three.js ?
Maybe it is possible to calculate the outer sides of the window and kind of extrude this case and make a primitive window and then CSG-substraction???
the most important thing is that we need a contour patch, which we can use for both 2D and 3D to build what we need.

[Model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEOSm.jpg)

I need to find points only on the contour of the 3D model.

Comment: Are you looking for a contour in one direction? If you rotate the camera, you will need a different contour i think.

Comment: Can you pre-process your window object and get what you want? Is this a dynamically created object?

Comment: @pailhead  This a gltf model provided by the designer and the outline needs to be from the front of the window

Comment: Ask the designer to provide you the outline from the front of the window.

Comment: @pailhead If we can't calculate it, we'll have to do it.((

Comment: If you yourself host some gltf that you got from the designer, again, the best thing would probably be to ask for `myGLTF_contour.gltf` or some json describing a polyline etc. 

If not, this can get very involved, and can depend much on the actual GLTF. Look up half edge structures.